# jQuery get DOM element as string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have

```
$(":input[type=text]:first")
```

How do I get

```
<input type="text" value="" size="28" maxlength="140" tabindex="1" placeholder="search" class="textbox" name="q" autocomplete="off">
```

Assuming I run this on SO?

**Update** I don't want to call `.parent()` since I have lots of other stuff in the parent element.

Comment: Just a note: you really should quote your attribute selectors.  `$(":input[type='text']:first")`.

Comment: Yeah it was merely an example, that's not the actual selector. I usually try and avoid using attribute selectors anyways.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get selected element's outer HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

Comment: @Rocket There's no difference using quotes in the attribute selector.

Comment: @lolwut: From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/): "Attribute values in selector expressions **must** be surrounded by quotation marks."

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[An old trick:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html?lq=1)

```
var selector = ":input[type=text]:first";

var str = $(selector).clone().wrap('<div/>').parent().html();
```

**Update** You don't need to worry about calling `.parent()` since you're working with an orphaned clone of the original selector.

Comment: Why is the clone important? If I'm creating an item on the fly, would that matter?

Comment: The inner element isn't created on the fly; it's being selected from the DOM, so we clone it to avoid altering the DOM.

Comment: What about $("a").html('').prop("outerHTML") ) ?

Comment: @ShulykVolodymyr Congratulations, you've just destroyed the contents of every anchor element on the page.

Comment: Is there any benefit of using this trick, as opposed to a concise @WDuffy answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32333935/1707382 ?

Answer (score 51):

How about

```
$(selector).prop("outerHTML");
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [jQuery.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) by appending to a created element.

```
$('<div/>').append($(":input[type=text]:first").clone()).html()
```

Here is a fiddle providing an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Zwbmx/1/

Comment: But you've now moved the original element out of the DOM.

Comment: This will remove the input from the DOM and append it to a newly created div.  You need to clone the input first.

Comment: @Rocket your right I modified the code to clone the element first.

Comment: LOL  Years later and I get the random downvote. And no comment left.

Answer (score 0):

Following on what @Blazemonger have answered, if you are going to send this html content to the server, it's worth to get rid of all unnecessary tags, white-spaces and line-breaks that don't add any value.

```
var quote = $(".invoice") //get hidden print-version DOM element
    .clone()
    .wrap('<div/>')
    .parent()
    .html()
    .replace(/    /g, '') //get rid of indentation spaces
    .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "") //get rid of line breaks
    .replace(/<!--[\s\S]*?-->/g, ""); //get rid of comment tags
```

My html had 50kb, after getting rid of this stuff, it got reduced to 4kb!

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
var str = $(selector)[0]
```

Maybe add a check that there is one element returned.