# angularjs Attempted to trust a non-string value context html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I insert my html view into the box? From id test1, into the vm.input variable?

```
angular.js:13920 Error: [$sce:itype] Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: html
```

Controller:

```
 vm.showbox = function(name) {
      console.log("testing name " + name);

      var a = angular.element('#' + name)[0];
      console.log(a);
      vm.inputbox =  $sce.trustAsHtml(a);

      console.log(vm.inputbox);
    };
```

view:

```
<div class"click"  ng-click="vm.showbox('test1')">click/div>

  <div  id="test1"  class="ng-hide">
        <h3>Shema</h3>
       schema here.
    </div>

     <div  style="display: block;"  ng-bind-html="vm.inputbox ">

        </div>
```

console log:

```
 <div  id="test1"  class="ng-hide">
        <h3>Shema</h3>
       schema here.
    </div>

angular.js:13920 Error: [$sce:itype] Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: html
```

Comment: That's your problem. $sce.trustAsHtml requires a string, and `angular.element` does not return a string, it returns a jQuery object. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: but the angular.element -> [0] returns me the div with id test1. How can i get the div to store it into vm.inputbox or show it somewhere?

Comment: I think that is the subject of a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127091/jquery-get-dom-element-as-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: How to resolve "Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996899/angularjs-how-to-resolve-attempting-to-use-an-unsafe-value-in-a-safe-context)

Answer (score 1):

```
app.filter('trustFilter', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}]);
```

You should use filter for it. And made some changes to like

```
<div style="display: block;" ng-bind-html="inputbox | trustFilter">
```

And In your controller

```
vm.inputbox = name;
```

`$sce.trustAs` requires a string value. maybe it will help

Comment: what exactly is your requirement ? You can refer to this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Comment: What i need is to get an element based on I'd and copy it within another div like I'm trying to do above .

Comment: just use this <div  style="display: block;"  ng-bind-html-unsafe="inputbox">